# How to add a counter to pandas duplicated index?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I want to transform duplicated values of index adding a counter like -01, -02, -0n, etc. for every duplicated item, skipping unduplicated indices.

That is to transform index values from these:

```
one
one
two
three
three
four
```

to these:

```
one-01
one-02
two
three-01
three-02
four
```

What approach can I resort to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter and assign only duplicated values by [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) with [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(6)},
                   index=['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'three', 'four'])


df.index += (df.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(2).radd('-')
                .where(df.index.duplicated(keep=False), ''))
print (df)
          a
one-01    0
one-02    1
two       2
three-01  3
three-02  4
four      5
```

Or use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df.index = np.where(df.index.duplicated(keep=False),
                    (df.index + df.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1)
                                  .astype(str).str.zfill(2).radd('-')),
                    df.index )
print (df)
          a
one-01    0
one-02    1
two       2
three-01  3
three-02  4
four      5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas!

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'three', 'four']})

df['A'] = df['A'].astype('category')

df['A'] = df['A'].cat.rename_categories(df['A'].cat.categories + '-' + df['A'].groupby(df['A']).cumcount().astype(str).str.zfill(2))
```

Comment: this code doesn't work for me